# getting rows with similar column value depending on max value of other column

Tags: sql

I have data set like following

```
FC  RC  aa  
F93 GT  16  
F92 GT  1  
F90 OT  48  
F94 AP  2  
F93 EU  2  
F90 NA  13  
F92 OT  1  
F92 SA  1
```

I would like the result to be:

```
FC  RC  aa  
F93 GT  16  
F90 OT  48  
F94 AP  2  
F93 EU  2  
F90 NA  13  
F92 SA  1
```

How I can achieve this?
I am using Oracle 11g database.

Comment: Please explain your logic behind *why* you should get your expected result.  I have no idea what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I have 2 rows for RC = 'GT' I want to get the FC with max(aa) for RC = 'GT'. Same is the case for RC = 'OT'

Answer (score 0):

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eccb74/2)**

```
SELECT FC, MAX(RC) RC, aa
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY FC, aa
```

**OUTPUT**

```
|  FC | RC | aa |
|-----|----|----|
| F90 | NA | 13 |
| F90 | OT | 48 |
| F92 | SA |  1 |
| F93 | EU |  2 |
| F93 | GT | 16 |
| F94 | AP |  2 |
```

Comment: Thanks very much! This worked! Appreciate the quick help.